# Indy > BroadCast to 172.30.58.255 fail

Tags: c++builder

My environment:

```
C++ Builder XE4
Indy 10.5.8.3
```

I am trying to broadcast to network 172.30.58.X with subnet mask 255.255.255.0.

Using TIdUDPClient, I tried following resulting in fail (no response).

```
// case1 
IdUDPClient1->BroadcastEnabled = true;
IdUDPClient1->BroadCast(cmd, port, L"172.30.58.255");
```

Instead, the following works, but from unlimited network (also including those other than 172.30.58.XXX)

```
// case2
IdUDPClient1->BroadcastEnabled = true;
IdUDPClient1->BroadCast(cmd, port, L"255.255.255.255");
```

With the Indy, how can I broadcast only to 172.30.58.XXX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing anything that accesses the `TIdUDPClient.Binding` property (such as `Broadcast()`, `Connect()`/`Active`, `Send/ReceiveBuffer()`, etc), set the `TIdUDPClient.BoundIP` property to the local IP that is connected to the `172.30.58.XXX` network.